# Object Rotating in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, kinematics

I'm making a square arm with push-pop matrix and pop-up menu entries. I want to make the objects rotate individually, so I create the code below but the one finger moves along with the others. Why is it moving together?

```cpp
void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    draw_lines();

    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)shoulder, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glPushMatrix();

    glScalef(2.0, 0.4, 1.5);
    glutWireCube(1.0); //First square(Shoulder)

    glPopMatrix();

    glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)elbow, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glPushMatrix();

    glScalef(2.0, 0.4, 1.5);
    glutWireCube(1.0); //Second Square(Elbow)

    glPopMatrix();

    glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)finger_1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(0.25, 0.0, 0.7);

    glPushMatrix();

    glScalef(0.5, 0.2, 0.2);
    glutWireCube(1.0); //First Finger

    glPopMatrix();

    glTranslatef(-0.3, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)finger_2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(0.25, 0.0, -0.4);

    glPushMatrix();

    glScalef(0.5, 0.2, 0.2);
    glutWireCube(1.0); //Second Finger

    glPopMatrix();

    glTranslatef(-0.3, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)finger_3, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(0.25, 0.0, -0.5);

    glPushMatrix();

    glScalef(0.5, 0.2, 0.2);
    glutWireCube(1.0); //Third Finger

    glPopMatrix();

    glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Object rotation is made by separate functions.

Comment: because you push pop ... with arms you should leave the translation and rotation otherwise you ignore previous part state .... the only thing to push/pop is scale for rendering sub part...

Comment: no you push before finger base then rotate render translate, then next bone of finger ... then pop and do the same for reach finger...

Comment: Hi, sometime ago I found this pdf document which is an excellent explanation of the concept

http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~frat/cg.fall13/5.hierarchy.pdf

I suggest to read it, it is a very good reading indeed.